# Date comparision using Linq

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a DateTime type column named "CreatedDate" in my sql table, and am passing the value for this column by using "DateTime.Now" from my asp.net application....

The datas in my CreatedDate column are,

```
 CreatedDate
 -----------
 2012-05-07 18:56:17.487
 2012-05-07 18:56:28.443
 2012-05-07 19:21:24.497
 2012-05-14 15:22:04.587
```

I need to get the datas with this `CreatedDate`.

in my entity framework I tried the condition like

```
DataAccess.Entities dataEntities = new DataAccess.Entities();

DataAccess.Employee employee = dataEntities.Employees
                              .First(e => e.CreatedDate == DateTime.Today);
```

like this, I have data for this date(2012-05-14) , but the mininutes part differes `(the DateTime.Today gives '2012-05-14 12:00:000' like this)` here, and it shows error like, sequence contains no element....

How can I compare the 'Date' alone in Linq.....can anyone help me here,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just declared two variable like

```
DateTime date1=DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime date2=DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1);
```

and in the condition I used these variables like

```
DataAccess.Employee employee = dataEntities.Employees
                          .First(e => e.CreatedDate >= date1 
                                   && e.CreatedDate < date2);
```

its working....

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Date` Property on the DateTime object

```
CreatedDate.Date==DateTime.Today
```

So your code will be

```
DataAccess.Employee employee=dataEntities.
                     Employees.First(e=>e.CreatedDate.Date==DateTime.Today);
```

`Date` Property returns the `Date` Component of the `DateTime` object and the time value set to `12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00)`.

Comment: but its showing error like "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: @Shanish: Is CreatedDate is of type Datetime ? If not what type it is ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DataAccess.Employee employee =
    dataEntities.Employees.First(e=>e.CreatedDate.Date==DateTime.Today)
```